# Api Console: Creating an OAuth 2.0 client id for an Android app - error "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it."

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

We accidently deleted an already created OAuth 2.0 client id for a specific package name / certificate hash in an API project.
When now trying to re-create this OAuth 2.0 client id for that package name / certificate hash we are getting the error "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it.".
Is there a way to re-activate such a deleted OAuth 2.0 client-id or to simply re-create it?

"Accidently deleted" because we fall into the problem that for testing and developing we used an other google account and wanted to re-create the OAuth 2.0 client id with the google account we use for publishing. But these seems to be not possible (Getting the same error). Using another package name or certificate is no option as the app is already published.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create another project with the same package name/hash pair, however you can restore the deleted project by selecting Undelete in the drop down menu on the left side of the page.

Comment: Its logic that we cannot create more than 1 project with the same package. But if we create the Project with account xxx@gmail.com, then I delete the project, it should be possible to create the project again with account yyy@gmail.com